# Get $HOME and/or username without using C++

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, home-directory, qml, qt5

I'm working on the Music app and I need to know how to get the user name and/or home dir of the users. I've googled around for a while but can only find the variables for C++ or BASH.

How do I get the user name or his/her home dir?

Comment: What language are you working with?

Comment: What language is the Music app?  Can you not use bash?

Comment: I'm writing in QML. I'm creating a Ubuntu Touch app without C++. And no. No bash.

Comment: I'd also suggest asking in the ubuntu-touch and ubuntu-touch-coreapps mailing lists, which is where the SDK developers hang out.

Comment: Maybe if you tell us why you need the user name and the path to their home folder someone might come up with a workaround or another way to do it.

Comment: David, I am a subscriber to those lists. I just didn't want to spam them and spammed here instead :P

I need the username to set the path to the users Music in ~/Music.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is any way to do this using QML only, without C++.  I am a C++ Qt developer, but I don't use QML much, so there may be some way that I am not aware of.

My understanding of QML is that it is primarily used for describing a UI for which any non-trivial backend code is implemented in either PyQt or C++.  Additionally, QML is meant to be completely cross-platform, and obtaining a User ID is not a platform agnostic operation.

If I were you and I was set on not using C++, I might try asking this question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).  There may be someone there with more expertise.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid of that. I'll give it a go on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Amit Tomar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093223/amit-tomar) for this answer:

You would have to get the Username in C++ and then exchange that data from C++ to qml.

QML and C++ objects can communicate with one another through signals, slots and property modifications. For a C++ object, any data that is exposed to Qt's Meta-Object System - that is, properties, signals, slots and Q_INVOKABLE methods - become available to QML. On the QML side, all QML object data is automatically made available to the meta-object system and can be accessed from C++.

Read [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtbinding.html) how to exchange data between QML and C++.